# script that create users and passwords from a .xls file

Tags: scripting, xls

I need to create users and passwords from an excel file for 20-25 persons.
lets say we have the list [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuiJi.png) i need a script to create them automatically , my teacher said pointers could be a way.
Will be used in a web interface based on a login page.
Any advice is welcome.

Comment: In which system do you need to create users? With or without password? It's totally unclear what the question is

Comment: The main purpose is to create vm's which student would connect via web interface , i need a script that can create users/passwords for each student from a xls list , and save them probably in a database( used for login) , debian9. Thank you for your time Thomas.

Comment: Please update your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask